# How to combine python variables into single row of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty dataframe:

```
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(columns=['combo', 'item1', 'item2', 'group1', 'group2', 'category1', 'category2', 'title1', 'title2'])
```

and then I have these values in seperate variables:

```
combo = 'A | B|'
item1 = 'A'
item2 = 'B'
group1 = 'phones'
group2 = 'cases'
cat1 = 'smartphones'
cat2 = 'leather cases'
title1 = 'Samsung galaxy S9+'
title2 = 'Casey for S9+'
```

I want to somehow get a dataframe row, that I could later append to my dataframe. Right now I am going through a for loop and using `.iloc[]` to put values into specific places, but is there a more optimal way..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create list of variables, in loop assign to nested lists and last pass to `DataFrame` constructor only once:

```
L = [combo, item1, item2, group1, group2, cat1, cat2, title1, title2]
cols = ['combo', 'item1', 'item2', 'group1', 'group2', 
        'category1', 'category2', 'title1', 'title2']

#simulate loop
out = []
for i in range(2):
    out.append(L)

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=cols)
print (dfObj)
    combo item1 item2  group1 group2    category1      category2  \
0  A | B|     A     B  phones  cases  smartphones  leather cases   
1  A | B|     A     B  phones  cases  smartphones  leather cases   

               title1         title2  
0  Samsung galaxy S9+  Casey for S9+  
1  Samsung galaxy S9+  Casey for S9+
```

Another solution is create dictionary:

```
d = {'combo': combo, 'item1': item1, 'item2': item2, 'group1': group1, 
     'group2': group2, 'category1': cat1, 'category2': cat2, 
     'title1': title1, 'title2': title2}
print (d)

out = []
for i in range(2):
    out.append(d)

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (dfObj)
     category1      category2   combo  group1 group2 item1 item2  \
0  smartphones  leather cases  A | B|  phones  cases     A     B   
1  smartphones  leather cases  A | B|  phones  cases     A     B   

               title1         title2  
0  Samsung galaxy S9+  Casey for S9+  
1  Samsung galaxy S9+  Casey for S9+
```